# How to use react-tournament-brackets library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I really don't understand how to use this "react-tournament-brackets" library

here is a link https://github.com/g-loot/react-tournament-brackets

i try to read but seems like it's so hard for me to understand this document

I use reactJS BTW.

can someone help me explain how to use this library? thank you

Comment: I don't use React (yet..begrudgingly learning it soon enough), and this seems reasonable. Is it an issue understanding what you're reading, or trouble using the code? If it's a reading issue that does come with time and effort. It's also a lot harder to try to help with, but I'm sure plenty of people could give pointers. If it's a running the code issue are you using a somehow-incompatible version of React?